# Boxcutter doesn't fill hole

Tags: mesh, modifiers, add-on

Boxcutter does not fill hole in this particular mesh while it did in others. Which settings will allow me to fill the gap when cutting?

[image]
[image]

Comment: is your cutter wider than the box? I don't think boxcutter will handle it if it's not. Other than that, maybe find the HOPS/boxcutter forums and ask there. Not a lot of BC users here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Booleans can create unpredictable topology, which can have unpredictable results.

Aside from making sure that the caps of the cylinder poke out both sides of your base object (it's hard to see by your screenshot), try changing the **Solver** setting from *Exact* to *Fast* or vice versa:

[image]

It may help.

Alternatively, play around with your base geometry to add or remove extra supporting edges. I recommend starting by having edges around the area where the cylinder is, to limit the amount of face area that is disturbed in the process.

Try placing edges here, for example:

[image]

You could also place similar supporting edges in your boolean shape. It gives the solver more entry points to work with in terms of creating vertices along the cut edge.

Fixing errors like these can be a balancing act of making sure you do so without breaking other areas of your mesh, and I find that what works for one situation won't necessarily be the same in every instance of that error.

It's hard to tell by your screenshot, but another reason for this could be because you've got a large ngon on that flat panel. Again, I can't tell from your screenshot - it could all be quads and edge loops, but I thought it was worth a mention.